# How to write a function that returns the bottom type?

Tags: agda, agda-mode

I am reading the PLFA book and reached the section [Negation](https://plfa.github.io/Negation/), and curious to know if I can implement a function that returns the bottom type:

```
foo : Set → ⊥ 
foo a = ?
```

It seems agda accepts my code, but I cannot find a way to implement the bottom set as there is no constructor. Can I actually do that?

Answer (score 2):

There is no function of type `Set → ⊥`, for exactly the reason you described: it is impossible to construct an element of type `⊥`. However, while it is not possible to return an *element of the `⊥` type*, you can write a function that *returns the `⊥` type* (since types are first-class objects in Agda):

```
bar : Set → Set
bar a = ⊥
```